# Does Rust detects duplicated closures (eg. ones defined in loop)?

Tags: loops, rust, closures, compiler-optimization

When I need to call many failable functions, I sometimes put them into closure.
Then I `?` them and catch any special variant (exception mechanism in other languages).

The following is my solution to https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a090c4e697598d0b9000004/train/rust .

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn solve(nums: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut sorted = VecDeque::from_iter(nums.iter().copied());
    sorted.make_contiguous().sort();

    let mut rearranged = vec![];
    while let Some(()) =
        (||->Option<()>{
            rearranged.push(sorted.pop_back()?);
            rearranged.push(sorted.pop_front()?);
            Some(())
        })()
    {}
    rearranged
}
```

Works fine and is clean, but I wonder,
“**Does Rust produce a closure *instance* on every** `while` loop **iteration”**?  (EDIT: I added the word *instance*)
If so, does it detect that produced closures are “just duplicates” of the first one
and optimizes duplication away?

I would be grateful for some theoretical consideration of cases when closure is defined inside the loop, like above. What optimizations compiler does to avoid duplication of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check is to have a look at the generated assembly, of course using `--release`.

Your code:

```
solve:
    pushq   %rbp
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $200, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, %r8
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB6_6
    movq    %rdx, %rbx
    movq    %r8, 128(%rsp)
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    shrq    $61, %rax
    sete    %al
    jne .LBB6_128
    movq    %rsi, %r14
    leaq    (,%rbx,4), %rdi
    movb    %al, %bpl
    shlq    $2, %rbp
    movq    %rdi, 104(%rsp)
    movq    %rbp, %rsi
    callq   *__rust_alloc@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB6_129
    movq    %rbx, 40(%rsp)
    leaq    (%r14,%rbx,4), %r12
    addq    $-4, %r12
    movq    %r12, %rbp
    subq    %r14, %rbp
    movq    %rbp, %rbx
    shrq    $2, %rbx
    leaq    4(%rbp), %rdx
    andq    $-4, %rdx
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    %r14, %rsi
    callq   *memcpy@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    leaq    1(%rbx), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    cmpq    $80, %rbp
    jae .LBB6_7
    movl    $1, %r15d
    cmpq    %r14, %r12
    movq    (%rsp), %r12
    je  .LBB6_106
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    leaq    (%r12,%rax,4), %r8
    addq    $-4, %r8
    leaq    (%r12,%rbx,4), %rcx
    addq    $4, %rcx
    movq    $-2, %rbp
    jmp .LBB6_97
```

Defining the closure in a variable ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=4d3302c60c5cba3883c058faaa5e56e0)):

```
solve:
    pushq   %rbp
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $200, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, %r8
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB6_6
    movq    %rdx, %rbx
    movq    %r8, 128(%rsp)
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    shrq    $61, %rax
    sete    %al
    jne .LBB6_128
    movq    %rsi, %r14
    leaq    (,%rbx,4), %rdi
    movb    %al, %bpl
    shlq    $2, %rbp
    movq    %rdi, 104(%rsp)
    movq    %rbp, %rsi
    callq   *__rust_alloc@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB6_129
    movq    %rbx, 40(%rsp)
    leaq    (%r14,%rbx,4), %r12
    addq    $-4, %r12
    movq    %r12, %rbp
    subq    %r14, %rbp
    movq    %rbp, %rbx
    shrq    $2, %rbx
    leaq    4(%rbp), %rdx
    andq    $-4, %rdx
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    %r14, %rsi
    callq   *memcpy@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    leaq    1(%rbx), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    cmpq    $80, %rbp
    jae .LBB6_7
    movl    $1, %r15d
    cmpq    %r14, %r12
    movq    (%rsp), %r12
    je  .LBB6_106
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    leaq    (%r12,%rax,4), %r8
    addq    $-4, %r8
    leaq    (%r12,%rbx,4), %rcx
    addq    $4, %rcx
    movq    $-2, %rbp
    jmp .LBB6_97
```

They're identical.

Comment: Thank you for this comparison. For me, it means that I don't need to explicitly „define closure in a variable” to get this optimization.
Do I understand it well?